# How to use $f^{n}$ is continuous non-zero at $x=a$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> If $f''(a),f'''(a),...,f^{n-1}(a)$ are $0$ but $f^{n}(x)$ is
>   continuous non-zero at $x=a$, then show that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0 }
>  (\theta_n-1) = \frac{1}{n}$ where:   $$f
> (a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+\frac{h^2}{2!}f''(a)+...+\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{n-1}(x+\theta_{n-1} h)$$

I don't see how to use the fact that $f^{n}(x)$ is continuous non-zero at $x=a$.

P.S: I think the the formula for $f(a+h)$ given in the book is wrong.

Comment: Is it $\theta_{n-1}$ or $\theta_n - 1$ in the limit?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $f(x) = C (x-a)^n$ with $C\neq 0$, then $f^{(n-1)}(x) = n! C (x-a)$  and

$$C h^n = f(a+h) = \frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}n! C \theta_{n-1} h \quad\Longrightarrow \quad \theta_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}$$